# $1\le r\le n$ and consider all $r-$element subset of $\{1,2,...,n\}$.$F(n,r)$ is the AM of the smallest elements of these subsets.

Tags: combinatorics

$1\le r\le n$ and consider all $r-$element subset of $\{1,2,...,n\}$.$F(n,r)$ is the AM of the smallest elements of these subsets.Prove that, $F(n,r)=\dfrac{n+1}{r+1}$

I know this is a famous problem, and it has solutions all around. One of the way it is done is bijection. But,  I cannot understand the solution. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What does the solution by bijection say? I don't really see how one would work, since $\binom{n}{r}$ need not be a multiple of $r+1$.

Comment: @ModdedBear Please see this http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=366639&sid=d928b56318c0c64517773d8713ed260e#p366639

Comment: which solution am I looking at?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you meant The solution by Boy Soprano II.

The mean is the sum over all the $r$-sets divided by the number of $r$-sets. The number of $r$-subsets is $\binom{n}{r}$

Hence If $S$ is the sum the mean is $\frac{S}{\binom{n}{r}}$. So we must prove $S=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$ to have $\frac{S}{\binom{n}{r}}=\frac{n-1}{r-1}$.

Lets try to count $S$. To do this we separate the sum. How many subsets have minimum element $j$? The other $r-1$ elements of such a set belong to the set $\{j+1,j+2\dots n\}$ of $n-j$ elements. Therefore there are $\binom{n-j}{r-1}$ such subsets.

So we can now write $S=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n j\binom{n-j}{r-1}$.

If we could prove this sum is equal to $\binom{n+1}{r+1}$ we would be done.

We will now prove $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n j\binom{n-j}{r-1}=\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ counting two ways

We count the $r+1$ subsets of $\{1,2,3\dots n,n+1\}$ in two ways.

Clearly there are $\binom{n+1}{r+1}$ such subsets.

On the other hand how many of these sequences have $k+1$ as the second smallest element? There are $k$ possible values for the smallest element and $\binom{n-k}{r-1}$ ways to select the $r-1$ largest values. Hence there are $k\binom{n-k}{r-1}$ subsets which have $k$ as the second largest element. Adding over the possible values for $k+1$  we get: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k\binom{n-k}{r-1}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$ as desired.

Comment: There are several typos: the second denominator in the *Hence if* line should be $\binom{n}r$; the index should be $j$, not $i$, in both occurrences of $\sum_{i=1}^nj\binom{n-j}{r-1}$; the righthand side in the *We will now prove* line should be $\binom{n+1}{r+1}$; and you’re counting the $(r+1)$-subseteq of $\{0,\ldots,n\}$, not of $\{1,\ldots,n+1\}$. Thus, the upper limit on $k$ is $n$, not $n+1$, and it does matter: $\binom{-1}{r-1}=(-1)^{r-1}(r-1)!$, not $0$, if $r\ge 1$.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I think it is ok now. :)